# "Resource Busy" error when trying to backup microSD to Macbook

Tags: backup, disk-utility, sd-card

As the title states, I'm trying to backup a microSD (input) to my Macbook Pro (output) running on Catalina.

I've used `diskutil list` to find the correct disk after which I run `sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk2 of=sd_backup.dmg bs=1m`. I've double- and triple-checked the disk number, so I'm sure it's correct. After a few minutes, it returns the following error:

```
dd: /dev/rdisk2: Resource busy
9+0 records in
9+0 records out
9437184 bytes transferred in 142.486616 secs (66232 bytes/sec)
```

I've searched Google extensively for a solution and I've seen that this is a recurrent issue for the *opposite* problem, i.e. restoring a microSD (output file) from a backup file stored on the MacBook (input file). In those cases, the solution has seemingly been to unmount the disk prior to restoring it, so I tried doing that in my case too by calling `sudo diskutil unmountDisk disk2`, seeing as I am new at this and figured it was worth a shot. That successfully unmounted my disk, but still changed nothing.

By following suggestions I've found on the internet, I have run `sudo fuser/Volumes/SAMSUNG_SD` after mounting it again which returns `/Volumes/SAMSUNG_SD: 146`. Using `sudo lsof -p 146`, i saw that a bunch of "mds" commands were running, which seems to be due to Spotlight. Therefore, I added my microSD to the Privacy list in Spotlight to prevent it from indexing it after which I killed the "mds" commands to force it to restart. Re-running `sudo fuser/Volumes/SAMSUNG_SD` after that yielded nothing, meaning that it worked. Still however, I am still getting the same error.

Finally, I tried directly through Disk Utility. There, after a few minutes I get an error during "Reading whole disk (DOS_FAT_32 : 0), with the same problem but this time with a reference to status 16, i.e. "Operation failed with status 16: Resource busy". I am at a loss. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try with Carbon Copy Cloner (free on month in test mode). It's the goodest program of backup on Mac ;-}